# SQL: Retain First Value Of the Group in other rows

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to retain value of Status in each group until status value changed.
For Example: For Status L, Rows number 2,3 should populate L in expected Status
Need Suggestion.

```
Rank Status  Expected_status
1     L      L
2     NULL   L
3     NULL   L
1     M      M
2     NULL   M
1     K      K
2     NULL   K
3     NULL   K
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(status IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts) Expected_status
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 ts, 1 rank, 'L' Status UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 3, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, 'M' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 1, 'K' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 2, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 3, NULL 
)
SELECT ts, LAST_VALUE(status IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts) Expected_status
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY ts
```

result is

```
Row ts  rank    Status  Expected_status  
1   1   1       L       L    
2   2   2       null    L    
3   3   3       null    L    
4   4   1       M       M    
5   5   2       null    M    
6   6   1       K       K    
7   7   2       null    K    
8   8   3       null    K
```

NOTE: you must have some column in your table that defines order of your rows - usually this is timestamp or day or position, etc. In my example I am assuming you have some timestamp column (I named it `ts` but yo might have different one).
Having `rank` column the way you have it in your example  - does not help as it does not allow to distinguish rows 2, 5 and 7 between each other!